# R: how to convert part of a string to variable name and return its value in the same string?

Tags: regex, r, variables

Suppose I have a string `marco <- 'polo'`. Is there any way I can embed `marco` in the middle of another string, e.g. `x <- 'John plays water marco.'` and have `x` return `'John plays water polo.'`?

EDIT

The solution David kindly offered does work for the hypothetical problem I posted above, but what I was trying to get to was this:

`data <- c('kek','koki','ukak','ikka')`

`V <- c('a|e|i|o|u')`

Rather than deleting all vowels, which the solution can manage (`gsub(V,'',data)`), how do I specify, say, all vowels between two k's? Obviously `gsub('kVk','',data)` doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like `gsub("marco", marco, x)`? Or `gsub(quote(marco), marco, x)`

Comment: Something among these lines `gsub(paste0("(?<=k)(",V,")(?=k)"), "", data, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, can you explain why the extra complexity beyond `gsub(paste0("k(",V,")+k","kk",data)` is necessary?

Comment: @BenBolker Because I'm not as smart as you I guess :)

Comment: What is the correct output for `keeuiokaeioukabcdedgk` ??

Comment: I think it depends on whether you apply the operation exhaustively, in which case there would be no vowels.

Comment: I tweaked the code around a bit and it's working great right now. Thanks everybody! Thank you David especially! You're a saint.

Answer (score 4):

If you want **all** vowels between two "k" letters removed, I propose the following:

```
V <- '[aeiou]'
data <- c('kek', 'koki', 'ukak', 'ikka', 'keeuiokaeioukaeiousk')
gsub(paste0('(?:\\G(?!^)|[^k]*k(?=[^k]+k))\\K', V), '', data, perl=T)
# [1] "kk"    "kki"   "ukk"   "ikka"  "kkksk"
```

The `\G` feature is an anchor that can match at one of two positions; the start of the string position or the position at the end of the last match. `\K`  resets the starting point of the reported match and any previously consumed characters are no longer included which is similar to a lookbehind.

[**Regular Expression Explanation**](http://regexdoc.com/re/explain.pl?re=%28%3F%3A%5CG%28%3F%21%5E%29%7C%5B%5Ek%5D*k%28%3F%3D%5B%5Ek%5D%2Bk%29%29%5CK%5Baeiou%5D&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

Comment: scary!   Can you explain or point to an explanation of your regexp?

Comment: I often ask myself what a twisted mind invented this language in the first place :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I want whatever they're smoking.

Comment: Pretty nifty tool you got there hwnd!

Answer (score 0):

Or, to use the example as given:

```
V <- 'a|e|i|o|u'  ## or equivalently '[aeiou]'
dd <- c('kek','koki','ukak','ikka','kaaaak')
gsub(paste0("k(",V,")+k"),"kk",dd)
## [1] "kk"   "kki"  "ukk"  "ikka" "kk"
```

I guessed that you might (?) want to delete *multiple* vowels between `k`s; I added a `+` to the regular expression to do this.

Comment: `V <- 'a|e|i|o|u'` is unnecessary ... Just `V <- '[aeiou]'`

Comment: I know, I was just doing it the way the OP did.